# Button not showing on MapKitView in the run time

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mapkit

I am trying to set a button on MapKitView. Unfortunately it is not showing in the run time. And  it is  set by  an auto suggest constraint .
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with  by making  `UIButton` view as subview of `MKMapView`.

For example :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet  var mapView: MKMapView!       

    @IBOutlet weak var _whareBtnView: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
              mapView.addSubview(_whareBtnView)

    }
}
```